# How to build mongodb c++ drivers for qtcreator application..?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am new to QtCreator and I have created a gui using C++.

I have following requirements:

1. How to install or import mongodb c++  drivers into Qt Creator?
   For this I have downloaded the drivers from the website. Extracted it. Now what to do? I  have no idea about how to compile those files.(Please suggest any detailed tutorial)
2. After importing the drivers I want to connect to the local mongodb database with default username and password.

Comment: Drivers for what? Where did you download from exactly, and did that site not have installation instructions? Your second question is something completely separate that your should first research, then post independently if you still have questions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the word "driver" in this question? Does this word mean some bindings to some other library that communicates with mongo? Or this is some completely independent library to connect mongo? Or you just downloaded mongodb itself? And what do you mean by loading "drivers" into Qt Creator? You want link some shared library to you project?

Comment: Somewhere I have seen that to connect to mongodb database I shouls have the c++ drivers. I have downloaded mongodb-win32-i386-v2.2-latest.zip this file. In instruction they have not given sufficient information. They said that I should first compile this drivers and then use in the project. I don't know how to compile this and use in project

Comment: user2123967: How to compile and install them is a matter of the mongodb drivers, not of Qt/Qt creator. How to use them from QtCreator on the other hand once installed is another thing. How that exactly works with the drivers I don't know, I assume one has to link against some library)